# UK outline basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, basemap, united-kingdom, outline

I am looking for a shapefile of the rough outline of the UK to use as a basemap, where is the best place to source one? All the shapefiles I have found have been extremely detailed with internal boundaries etc.

Comment: @MAJ742 - small nuance here, OP wishes low resolution data

Comment: @GISGe - I spotted that, but the accepted answer to the question mentions the OSM data and that it is available in a variety of resolutions so figured that would probably still be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [Eurostat's Geodata page](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries#countries14) you can download shapefiles of country boundaries (worldwide) for use at different scales (less detailed scale is 1:60 million).

There is a line and a polygon shapefile.